# How to find the "dangerous pages" in Google Webmaster Tools?

Tags: google-search-console

In google webmaster tools how can I find the dangerous pages in my website? i.e When I check the security of my website in Google, it says there are dangerous pages in my website.

So how can I rectify them?

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing this "dangerous pages" message?

Answer (score -1):

"Fetch and render" pages of your website in GWT. In your Google Webmaster click on "Fetch as Google" under the crawl tab and then submit each page URL there. Don't click on "Fetch", click on "Fetch and render" to see the status of your web page. Hope this will help to know your web pages status.